# Substraction of rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a pandas dataframe

```
Customer   Date          price
Jane       01/01/2018    10
Jane       01/02/2018    14
Joe        01/01/2018    10
Joe        01/02/2018    15
```

I want a group data by customer but substract price of `01/02/2018` and `01/01/2018`.

```
Customer   price
Jane       4
Joe        5
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I thought of multiplying all the 01/01/2018 values by -1 and make groupby sum but I want something pythonic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Customer as index and then groupby and diff:

```
df.set_index('Customer', inplace=True)
df.groupby('Customer').diff().dropna().astype(int)
```

Output:

```
          price
Customer    
Jane      4
Joe       5
```